# Display Text in Django Form

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with a customer and buildings.

```
class Building(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, verbose_name="Kunde")
    street = models.CharField("Straße", max_length=32)
    house_number = models.CharField("Hausnummer", max_length=4)
    zip = models.IntegerField("Postleitzahl")
    place = models.CharField("Ort", max_length=32)
    ...

class Customer(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField("Straße", max_length=32)
    house_number = models.CharField("Hausnummer", max_length=4)
    zip = models.IntegerField("Postleitzahl")
    place = models.CharField("Ort", max_length=32)
    ...
```

If the customer-adress and the building-adress is the same, the adress-data in the building should be null.

In my BuildingCreateView I want to show a text in the TextBoxes for the adress like: "only if differ from customer".

How to do this?
The default value of these fields should be null.

Answer (score 2):

help_text modelfield's attribute is your friend : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#help-text

```
street = models.CharField(
    verbose_name='Straße', 
    max_length=32,
    blank=True, null=True, 
    help_text='Only if...'
)
```